# Package responsible for syllable division

Tags: packages

In my text I do have some lines with words including syllable divisions. I would like to avoid searching for the responsible package by commenting them out individually as this surely leads to error messages and so on. Therefore, can anyone tell me in short what typical packages are responsible for syllable division or have this ability included in them? Thanks

Comment: Here's a start: http://ctan.org/topic/hyphenation But this is precisely why you shouldn't just include a laundry list of packages without knowing what they do or why (if) you need them.

Comment: What do you mean by "syllable division? Hyphenation? Or maybe something else? Please advise.

Comment: assuming you mean hyphenation (it's hard to tell from the question)  it isn't really at the package layer but built in to the tex engine, however hyphenation is specified per language, and most people use the `babel` package to switch languages.

Comment: If you really mean syllable divisions, the `soul` package has some hooks for doing things after every syllable (e.g. `\SOUL@everysyllable`). I saw `soul` used in a preamble to one of your other questions, but without seeing some code that exhibits the issue (or even a better explanation of the issue) it's hard to say.

Comment: Sorry for the admittedly too short information.

Comment: One possible solution for my syllable division (e.g. di-vi-sion) in my case was the following package: \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
Other packages may well cause such issues, too.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Not sure if an answer to that question can be really helpful, especially with respect to the comment directly above.

Comment: @Johannes_B I suspect vote "unclear" is thing to do after all this time